# Retorno de consulta por ordem decrescente

Tags: php, cakephp, phpmyadmin, php-7, cakephp-2

Com este código, como procedo para que o retorno da consulta venha em ordem **decrescente**?

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once "conexao.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>CRUD - Pesquisar</title>     
    </head>
    <body>
    <center>
        <a href="http://localhost/aula/index.php">
<button> Menu </button> </a>


        <h1>Pesquisar Pré Picking</h1>
        <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])){
            echo $_SESSION['msg'];
            unset($_SESSION['msg']);
        }
        ?>
        <form method="POST" action="">
            <label>Nome: </label>
            <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Digite o nome"><br><br>

            <input name="SendPesqUser" type="submit" value="Pesquisar">
        </form><br><br>

        <?php
        $SendPesqUser = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'SendPesqUser', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        if($SendPesqUser){
            $nome = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM pessoas1  '; WHERE nome LIKE '%$nome%  ORDER BY `data` DESC";
            $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
            while($row_pessoas1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario)){
                 echo "ID:" . $row_pessoas1['id'] . "<br>";
                  echo "Nome:" . $row_pessoas1['nome'] . "<br>";
                  echo "Rua:" . $row_pessoas1['rua'] . "<br>";
                  echo "Tipo:" . $row_pessoas1['tipo'] . "<br>";
                  echo "Lista:" . $row_pessoas1['lista'] . "<br>";
                  echo "Data:" . $row_pessoas1['data'] . "<br><hr>";
                echo "<a href='edit_usuario.php?id=" . $row_pessoas1['id'] . "'>Editar</a><br><hr>";

            }
        }
        ?>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não tem este ; antes do WHERE. O ; indica o final de um comando SQL.

Comment: perdão não entendi aquele ordr by eu coloquei mais não deus certo deconsidere ele

Comment: como ficaria o codigo que mandei

Comment: $result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM pessoas1 WHERE nome LIKE '%$nome%'  ORDER BY `data` DESC;";

Comment: Nota 1,000 funcionou 100 % muito obrigado !!!

Comment: como resolveu, vale colocar a solução como resposta para que a pergunta não permaneça aberta ([por que aceitar uma resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta)) ;)

Answer (score 0):

> *Como coloquei no comentário, para que a pergunta não fique sem resposta, colocarei a sugerida aqui*

---

O erro é `';` antes do `where`; a consulta deve ficar da seguinte forma:

```
$result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM pessoas1 WHERE nome LIKE '%$nome%' ORDER BY data DESC;";
```